# Website screenshot with html2canvas and resize it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html2canvas

i'm tried to capture a screenshot from an external website and then resize it for insert result in my page.
I use html2canvas but I can not understand how I can make a screenshot of an external page and then resize it.
I have tried like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
function appcanvas() {
html2canvas("http://www.yahoo.com", {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
});
      }
    </script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Invia" onclick="appcanvas();" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but it does not work
Anyone have some advice for me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a same-origin issue, you cannot make requests to other domains in Javascript this way.

Comment: and if i store the html content of the page with a php script in a variable and then pass it at my script is a possible way?

Comment: If you download all of their images to your server as well, yes. Otherwise it will just be the HTML without any images (same-origin policy applies to images as well)